# Android internal URI schema reason

Tags: android, performance, uri, android-contentprovider

I would like to understand why does Android has its own URI schema, with URIs like

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A11
```

At the beginning I thought it was for security reasons, to avoid applications from getting information about the directory structure and surf it at their will. But I have seen you can query the DB and get the full path as in a classical FS schema.

My question is, why did they then designed such schema? Is is for efficiency reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android URIs simply follow the [RFC 3986 format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

The URI in your example is formatted that way for semantic reasons. The main reason for this is that content URIs may not always refer to a file-system object. What if the content is in a database (for example as a phone contact) instead of on the file-system? Using this schema allows you to access content irrespective of how it is stored.

Comment: Brilliant example. It is much more clear now. Thanks!